# disable Excel UserForm fade-in & fade-out animation

Tags: excel, vba, user32, userform

Using VBA in Excel 2007 (and 2010), is there a way to disable the standard fade-in and fade-out animations when showing and hiding a UserForm.  The fade-out, in particular, is too slow for the user interface I'm trying to create.

Perhaps the `user32` function [`AnimateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632669%28VS.85%29.aspx) has a setting that can be voided, but I haven't figured that out.

**Edit**: This is an aesthetic goal; there are no performance problems. The fade-out with `Me.Hide`, as handled by the OS, takes ~1/2 second and I'd like to know if it can be overriden to be instantaneous.

Comment: I am not too sure what do you mean? The fade out when you call `Unload Me` is not fast? I am curious as to what do you mean by `is too slow for the user interface I'm trying to create`

Answer (score 0):

VBA does not have any built in properties for User Form animations on load/unload.

It's handled by the OS.  Have you tried to [Turn off Visual Effects](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Optimize-Windows-7-for-better-performance) to see if the response is better? (hint:  adjust for best performance)

If this is not the problem, it would help to post code that's causing the problem.  (assuming it's more than just *Me.Hide* or *Unload Me*)